# Post JSON and Submit Form (or redirect)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm struggling with how to properly submit a form where I really only need to send the JSON and not the form controls. I have a SubmitOrder() javascript function:

```
function SubmitOrder() {
    var selectedProductsAsJson = JSON.stringify(selectedProducts);
    // This line works...
    $.post('/OrderCheckout/Save', { jsonData: selectedProductsAsJson });
    // ... or this line works...
    $('#productListForm').submit();
    // but not both lines together.
}
```

What I'm trying to do is send selectedProductsAsJson to my controller, process it, then send the user to a new page. The $.post line accomplishes the first two actions, but I don't know how to send the user to a new page after that.

If I just do the .submit() line, the user is redirected to the new page, but the controller doesn't have the json data to process.

If I use both lines, the $.post call is asynchronous and the user will end up on the new form before the $.post call completes. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418402/279516) that I can make the $.post call synchronous, but it seems like I should be able to do all of this with one call to the server. What am I missing to make this happen?

My controller currently looks like this;

```
public class OrderCheckoutController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public void Save(string jsonData)
    {
        List<Product> selectedProducts = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Product>>(jsonData);
        decimal totalPrice = selectedProducts.Sum(x => x.Price);
        ViewBag.SaleTotal = totalPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we need some clarification. Why do you need 2 round trips to the server to accomplish your goal? Why can't it just be one endpoint?

Comment: That's actually exactly what I'm trying to do: one trip. I'm making two right now because it's the only way I know how to: (1) get my JSON data to the controller, then (2) submit the form and get to the next view/page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the success callback function (third parameter) of [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

The "success url" can be hard coded or come from your POST (`Save`) action (which is actually void, but could be a JsonResult)

```
$.post('/OrderCheckout/Save', 
       { jsonData: selectedProductsAsJson }, 
        function() {
          $('#productListForm').submit();
        }
      );
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Now I have to deal with why the new page isn't showing ViewBag.SaleTotal. Does the Index() method need to do that, or should it work as-is in the Save() method?

Comment: @BobHorn Well, ViewBag won't work, I think, but you could return it from Save method (doing it a JsonResult, not a void), and populate an hidden field of your productListForm in the success callback.

Comment: I was able to get that to work by using a static variable on the controller. The Save() method set it, then the Index() method used it to set the ViewBag value.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Save(string jsonData)
{
    List<Product> selectedProducts = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Product>>(jsonData);
    decimal totalPrice = selectedProducts.Sum(x => x.Price);
    ViewBag.SaleTotal = totalPrice;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

---

OR

```
$.post('/OrderCheckout/Save', { jsonData: selectedProductsAsJson }, 
        function() {
          $('#productListForm').submit();
        }
);
```

Comment: I actually tried that before posting my question. I just tried it again to remember why it didn't work, and the issue is that the user isn't sent to the new page. The same page is still showing.

Comment: Your `$('#productListForm').submit();` should be place in `$.post`'s success callback  function.

Comment: Ah... gotcha. So that makes this basically the same as the other answer (including where to go upon success). Thanks!